# Statistics (Likelihood ratio stat.)

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots, Y_n$ are independent $N(\alpha,σ^2)$
Show that, if $\sigma$ is unknown, the likelihood ratio statistic for testing a value of $\alpha$ is given by $$D = n \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}T^2\right)\;,$$ where $$T = \frac{\hat{α} -\alpha}{\sqrt{s^2/n}}$$

Comment: You haven't told us enough.  Presumably the two parameters $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ should index a family of probability distributions.  What family of distributions are you applying this to?

Comment: Please check to see that this is what you intended: there were some mismatched parentheses in the original, and the intent wasn’t entirely clear.

Comment: I think the recent edits make it clear.  You're asking why the standard Student's t-test is a likelihood-ratio test.  The way it's expressed here, with the test statistic depending only on $T^2$, you'd have to have a simple one-point null hypothesis and a two-sided alternative hypothesis.  If I were presenting this to a class of students who know how to do only what they've been told how to do, I wouldn't give it as an exercise, but I might do it in class.  For the kind who can be given the relevant definitions and then figure things out, it's not a bad exercise.

Comment: ....and I've done it in front of classes a couple of times.

Comment: I up-voted this question after the necessary clarifications were done.  But still at this time the vote total is $-1$.  Is there something objectionable about the question?

Comment: Glad you got it, max.  Could you "accept" my answer?  (I.e. click on the green check-mark.)

Answer (score 3):

OK, a moderately thin sketch.  It's useful to know this algebraic identity:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \alpha)^2 = n(\overline{x} - \alpha)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x})^2, \tag{1}
$$
where $\overline{x}= (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$.  That means if you seek the value of $\alpha$ that minimizes this, you only need to look at the first term on the right above.  That value of $\alpha$ maximizes the likelihood function $L=L(\alpha,\sigma)$, since $L$ depends on $\alpha$ only through the sum (1), and $L$ is a decreasing function of that sum.  Since the value $\hat\alpha$ of $\alpha$ that maximizes $L$ does not depend on $\sigma$, you can then just plug in that value to $L$, getting $L(\hat\alpha,\sigma)$, and find the value of $\sigma$ that maximizes that.  You will see that that makes one of the two terms in (1) vanish.  You'll end up with
$$
L = \frac {1}{\sigma^n} \exp\left( \frac{-(\text{something})}{2\sigma^2} \right).
$$
To find the value $\hat\sigma$ of $\sigma$ that maximizes that, just realize that since $\ln$ is an increasing function, it's the same as the value that maximizes
$$
\ell = \ln L = -n\ln\sigma - \frac{\text{something}}{2\sigma^2}.
$$
Once you've got $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\sigma$, you need the likelihood ratio, either
$$
D = \frac{L(\hat\alpha,\hat\sigma)}{L(\alpha_0,\hat\sigma)},
$$
or
$$
D = \frac{L(\alpha_0,\hat\sigma)}{L(\hat\alpha,\hat\sigma)}
$$
(depending on which way you want to do it), where $\alpha_0$ is the value of $\alpha$ given by the null hypothesis.

What you get should be a monotone function of $T^2$, so you reject the null hypothesis if $T^2$ is too big.

I'll leave it to you to work through details and bring up further questions about those if necessary.

Comment: Maybe I should add that in the expression $L(\alpha_0,\hat\sigma)$, the $\hat\sigma$ is not the same as the $\hat\sigma$ that appears in $L(\hat\alpha,\hat\sigma)$, since it's the value that maximizes $L$ with $\alpha$ fixed at $\alpha_0$.  You get $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\alpha_0)^2$, whereas in the other one you get  $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x})^2$.